# Using custom LocalMessages apart from Locales

Tags: gwt, localization, internationalization

We're are having problems to customize the *I18N* functionality of GWT.

We are currently using a static property file to generate our interfaces we use in the code.  Apart from loading the default locales like "*de*" or "*en*" at runtime we are also looking for a way to load custom language files dependent of another property (e.g. called "*dist*").

In detail:

In our *.gwt.xml* we have both properties defined like this:

```
<extend-property values="de" name="locale"/>
<extend-property values="en" name="locale"/>
<define-property name="x.dist" values="dist1,dist2,dist3"/>
```

We now want to have one language file which contains all generic properties, and for each distribution and language other language files which can contain special values.
All these interfaces should also be generated automatically with the *maven gwt plugin* "*i18nMessagesBundle*".

We already tried to use a "SpecialLocalMessage" interface which extends all the special dist interfaces but we were not able to replace those in the gwt.xml via `"<replace-with>"` because there are classes but not interfaces required.

Do you see any solution for this problem?

Comment: <replace-with> will only run at compile time, whereas the maven goal I18nMessageBundle runs before the compiler runs and creates the interfaces the compiler will use. I cannot see any way to do what you want other than actually writing an application like I18NMessageBundle yourself to create the interfaces and then call it with a custom maven goal which you run before compiling.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to use language sub-sets, like en_US or en_UK (I think nothing stops you from having things like en_dist1, en_dist2 as well!) to add more special values on top of the normal en or de values. You wouldn't need to have your custom property then, which makes things a whole lot easier.

Comment: I've also asked this at the GWT mailing list and got a good response there. Just wanted to share that here again:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/nW9jL9tQuDI/rVUSAXjiUWcJ